# Install a package from SSH

Tags: linux, software-installation, gnu-screen

This is my first experience with Linux. I want to install a package (named `screen`) and I have access to a SSH login which I use `putty` on Windows to do so. Is there a way to install `screen` from `putty` or should I ask my VPS provider to install it?

Comment: There almost certainly is a way to install it but *how* will depend what distribution of Linux you are running on the VPS - which you haven't told us

Comment: @steeldriver how should I know the login info? I just know the login and I'm new to linux world

Comment: The output of `lsb_release -a` would be enough to tell us what distro you are running.  If lsb_release isn't installed, then the output of `uname -r` would probably be good, depending on your VPS.

Comment: @jsbillings thanks. `lsb_release` was not installed and the output of `uname -r` is this: `2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64`

Comment: looks like a redhat, have you a file name /etc/redhat-release ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your linux distro is Red Hat Enterprise Linux-based, most likely CentOS if it is a hosted environment.  It looks like you're using the kernel from version 6.7.

The simplest way to install `screen` is to to run `sudo yum install screen` as your regular user.

Also, the kernel you are running is very out of date.  "2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64" is the kernel that shipped with CentOS 6.7, and has had several updates since it came out last year.  You will want to run `sudo yum upgrade` frequently, or set up the "yum-cron" service to automatically download and apply updates periodically.

Comment: thanks. I successfully installed it. Not sure why anyone would downvote your answer but I upvoted hence the 0 total.

Comment: I did add a comment, but it seems it didn't post/got deleted.  I believe the last sentence is poor advice, an over simplification.  Simply allowing a server to update itself with no regard for what might break isn't a good idea.  Been bitten by it more than once and now ensure I have a regular update schedule where I assess what needs upgrading and can preempt breakages.  That said, there are times when scheduling blind updates is acceptable, but assessment is required.

Comment: I'd agree if more people were as willing as you to evaluate updates. yum-cron can be configured to only apply security updates, although it won't work on CentOS. At least it's getting updates. Simply said, a broken system with security updates is better than a working system with known remote exploits. At least, for everyone else.